# attach vb6 application with sql server process

Tags: vb6, sybase, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have front end designed in VB6.I have database as Sybase server.

I am debugging vb6 application to fix one issue,i want to attach the vb6 application with sybase server so that the debugger gets attached with the stored procedure at the time of debugging itself.
I am not able to debug the back end stored procedure from the front end UI.

Please help me out .

thanks,

Comment: As far as I know, for VB6, it would have a limitation, but we can debug stored procedures within SQL Server.